# SQL Server 2005 - Insert with Select for 1 Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-insert

Basically I have 2 tables but the problem is I would like to insert data from table A column A to table B column C.

But when I try to this I get an error

My subquery is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Id] 
From [A]
Where [B] = 'ValueCon'
```

And here is my insert query

```
INSERT INTO [B]
       ([BA]
       ,[BB]
       )
VALUES
       ('TestData'
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 [Id] 
        From [A]
        Where [AB] = 'ValueCon')

       )
```

There is no need to worry about data types as they are all matching.

I get the following error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

I have seen many complex ways of getting around this but just need something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be if you use a declared param, you can use it to the INSERT

```
DECLARE @theInsertedId INT;

SELECT TOP 1 @theInsertedId=[Id] 
From [A]
Where [B] = 'ValueCon'

INSERT INTO [B]
       ([BA]
       ,[BB]
       )
VALUES
       ('TestData'
       ,@theInsertedId

       )
```

Sorry for by bad english! Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

[Read up on the proper syntax for `INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)! It's all very well documented in the SQL Server Books Online ....

**Either** you have `INSERT` and `VALUES` and you provide **atomic** values (variables, literal values), e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [B] ([BA], [BB])
VALUES ('TestData', @SomeVariable)
```

**OR** you're using the `INSERT ... SELECT` approach to select column from another table (and you can also mix in literal values), e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [B] ([BA], [BB])
   SELECT    
       TOP 1 'TestData', [Id]
   FROM [A]
   WHERE [AB] = 'ValueCon'
```

but you cannot mix the two styles. Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have a single select statement?

Not sure if this will work for what you are trying to do....

```
declare @a table 
(
ab varchar(20),
id varchar(20)
)

insert @a
select 'ValueCon',1
union all
select 'ValueCon',2
union all
select 'Con',100

declare @b table 
(
ba varchar(20),
bb varchar(20)
) 


insert @b (ba,bb)
select top 1 'TestData',id from @a where ab='Valuecon'

select * from @a
select * from @b
```